# Anylogic Take first entry of collection and delete said entry

Tags: java, anylogic

I would like to take the first entry of my collection and - after having used it - delete it from said collection.
I haven't found anything in the API of Anylogic, only the possiblity to delete all entries at once (which I do not want to do).
Is it possible to delete only one entry? And do the others change their index automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either change the collection type of `LinkedList` and use:

```
collection.removeFirst();
```

Or keep it an array list and use:

```
collection.remove(0);
```

Comment: nope, anylogic says it is undefined for the type ArrayList :(

Comment: I didn't know it was an array list. I updated my answer.